# How to get relative counts/frequency in mySQL with a single query

Tags: mysql, performance, frequency

I want to get relative counts/frequency of values (can be many) in the column.
From this toy table `numbers`:

```
 num
  1
  2
  3
  1
  1
  2
  1
  0
```

This one:

```
num | count 
 0  | 0.125
 1  | 0.5
 2  | 0.25   
 3  | 0.125
```

I can do this with a variable and two queries:

```
SET @total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers);
SELECT num, ROUND(COUNT(*) / @total, 3) AS count
FROM numbers
GROUP BY num
ORDER BY num ASC
```

But how I can get the results in one query (without listing all the possible values of `num`)? 
If I am querying joins of several tables, then even getting a total number of rows becomes quite long and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windowing functions -

```
SELECT DISTINCT num,
    ROUND(CAST(COUNT(1) OVER (Partition by num) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(1)OVER() AS DECIMAL),3) AS [count]
FROM numbers
ORDER BY num ASC
```

`COUNT(num)` would give the same results, it's personal preference for me to count a supplied value per row rather than counting the value in the rows, the partitioning handles which rows are included in the count.

Note the counts need to be cast as decimal, otherwise your division will be integer division, giving you wrong numbers.

Using DISTINCT instead of GROUP lets your windowing function apply to the whole table, not just each group within that table, and still only returns one result per num.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a39a6/3)

Comment: this does not works, because `count(1) over()` will return 4 instead of 8. this also was my first approach :)

Comment: @bruno.almeida Then try this instead, remove the grouping and return DISTINCT rows

Comment: yes, it works. (why comments must be at least 15 characters in length? lolol)

Comment: @bruno.almeida To prevent "thanks", "+1", "me too" etc. Comments have a minimum length to try and make sure they have some substance to them.

Comment: @RickJames It is supported by a version of MySQL that came out a year and a half ago, and is the best answer to what the question asks.

Comment: @Andrew - I would venture to say that more than half the readers of stackoverflow are more than 2 years behind on upgrading.  My Comment was merely a warning to them, not a downvote for your Answer.  However, I suspect the use of square brackets will give a syntax error in all versions of MySQL.  And `CASTing` is probably unnecessary.

Comment: @RickJames casting is required, without it the division is interger division and does not return the wanted answers.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This is tested in msSql, misread question!

You can try this:

```
--DROP TABLE numbers
CREATE TABLE numbers(num decimal(16,3))

INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(0)

SELECT
    num,
    CAST(numCount as DECIMAL(16,2)) / CAST(sum(numCount) over() AS decimal(16,2)) frequency
FROM (
    SELECT 
        num,
        count(num) numCount
    FROM
        numbers
    GROUP BY
        num
) numbers

num frequency
0.000   0.1250000000000000000
1.000   0.5000000000000000000
2.000   0.2500000000000000000
3.000   0.1250000000000000000
```

Comment: A query with a subquery still is two queries, instead of using a variable to hold the result of one query you do it inside the second, where the variable would be.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the same number of keystrokes, and about the same performance, but it is only one statement:

```
SELECT  n.num, ROUND(COUNT(*) / t.total, 3) AS count
    FROM ( SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total FROM  numbers ) AS t
    JOIN  numbers AS n
    GROUP BY  n.num
    ORDER BY  n.num ASC
```